# Is there a trope for people that are quite harmless on their own but when paired with 'this guy' they could make a chaos towards their surroundings?

Tags: terminology, trope

For example Jesse and Walter from *Breaking Bad*, on their own they are not so 'catastrophic', but every time they are working together, they always seem to bring the worst possible situations, be that to themselves or to their enemies even their most cautious enemy. It's like the worst nightmare for everyone that's involved with them both.

Is there a trope for that kind of situation?

**Update** : Apologies, it appears that I'm at fault for not explaining my question clearly.

What I mean by trope is a figurative or metaphorical use of a word or expression, in my case it's trope that appeared quite often in tv or movies.

For examples, trope about [Playing against the type](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlayingAgainstType), which in a nutshell refer to actor that are usually played as one type of character like a happy go lucky guy, suddenly they played as a serial killer character.

Another example is [MundaneMadeAwesome](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MundaneMadeAwesome), which basically referring to attempts to make seemingly dull or unimportant action looked like 'huge importance' by giving the scene things like dramatic lighting, extreme close-ups, Exaggerated expressions and gestures.

Those are some examples of trope that I was talking about.

So my point is, is there a trope (figurative or metaphorical use of a word or expression) for a situation like specific people that when they are together (I'm not talking about a couple) or doing something together, they always invites disastrous situation for everyone (even those who are like specialized against people like these) that are involved, including themselves? Maybe like disastrous duo? (which is not a trope apparently)

I hope I cleared some of the confusions.

Comment: A divorcing  couple......   :)    It was there I couldn't resist :)

Comment: Mmm -  I'm wondering whether this might be better asked on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't really see how this is about movies & TV at all, other than employing *Breaking Bad* as a mere example. It seems more like the request for terminology referring to some everyday social construction. Neither is your second question on-topic, since we're not entertaining questions asking for film recommendation lists here, so I removed that part entirely. But now it seems not related to movies & TV at all anymore.

Comment: Toxic relationship? [Destructive romance](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DestructiveRomance)? A match made in hell? ;)

Comment: Why not go to http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/BreakingBad and look through the list? And your question remains off-topic here, IMHO.

Comment: I've looked at all the tropes listed in the show from there, it doesn't included that. The problem is sometimes tvtropes missed or doesn't included tropes that a show actually had, which is why I asked here.

Well I thought that given there's trope and terminology tag in here, I think it's not that off-topic? I mean I'm just asking if there's trope for that kind of situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not movies specific

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not movies specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking Bad was an incredible show and over its five seasons, hit a massive amount of tropes.

I looked through several of the Duo Tropes of the site and the individual ones used in Breaking Bad.

They are each other's [Poisonous Friend](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoisonousFriend)

> Walter White is this to Jesse Pinkman in Breaking Bad. While Jesse wasn't completely innocent before getting into business with Walt, it's undeniable that his life has taken a definite turn for the worse because of Walt's influence. Walt even manages to manipulate Jesse into killing Gale in cold blood. Jesse is equally poisonous to Walt, if usually unintentionally, and in a completely different way: while his sincerity might be debatable, we continue to see Walt go to impressive lows in order to ensure Jesse's safety, despite the fact that he is an emotionally volatile wild card and a liability. Add this to the fact that Jesse is the one who gets Walt into the drug business in the first place, and you have a recipe for one of the most mutually poisonous friendships on television. One so toxic, it has a collateral death count of close to a hundred, if not in the hundreds.